# Importing a JSON file with Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, import

I'm trying to import a JSON file within a typescript file using the `import` statement. However I'm getting the following error when trying to do so :

> SyntaxError: C:\Users\Treycos\Documents\Personal\Web extensions\LocalTube\src\background\download-config.json: Unexpected token, expected ";" (2:8)

My `tsconfig` with `"resolveJsonModule"` set to `true` (Typescript 3.5) :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Here is the JSON file :

```
{
    "IP": {
        "home": "",
        "local": "localhost",
        "server": ""
    },
    "port": {
        "node": 8081,
        "asp": 64688
    },
    "path": {
        "express": "download",
        "asp": "api/audio"
    }
}
```

The import statement (no warning message) :

```
import * as config from './download-config.json'
```

The autocomplete works perfectly within the typescript file:
[image]

Stack trace :

```
ERROR in ./src/background/download-config.json
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Treycos\Documents\Personal\Web extensions\LocalTube\src\background\download-config.json: Unexpected token, expected ";" (2:8)

  1 | {
> 2 |     "IP": {
    |         ^
  3 |         "home": "",
  4 |         "local": "localhost",
  5 |         "server": ""
    at Object.raise (C:\Users\Treycos\Documents\Personal\Web extensions\LocalTube\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:6325:17)
    at Object.unexpected (C:\Users\Treycos\Documents\Personal\Web extensions\LocalTube\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7642:16)
    at Object.semicolon (C:\Users\Treycos\Documents\Personal\Web extensions\LocalTube\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7624:40)
    at Object.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\Treycos\Documents\Personal\Web extensions\LocalTube\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10364:10)
    at Object.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\Treycos\Documents\Personal\Web extensions\LocalTube\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9963:19)
    at Object.parseStatement (C:\Users\Treycos\Documents\Personal\Web extensions\LocalTube\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9829:17)
```

---

EDIT

Webpack config :

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    background: "./src/background/QueryHandler.ts",
    popup: "./src/popup/popup.html",
    content: './src/content/Mapper.ts'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {}
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
              exportAsEs6Default: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[path][name].[ext]',
            }
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

What could be causing this issue ?

Comment: This doesn't happen to me; At what stage is this happening? Fro,m your stacktrace, it looks like a babel issue, not tsconfig

Comment: Uh, weird, I'll post my webpack config too. It happens when I use the `webpack` command, without any options

Comment: So... I just commented out the babel section of my webpack config (even though it is supposed to target js and jsx files) and now... it compiles just fine for some reason. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from my webpack config.

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
          }
        }
      }
```

The regex `/\.(js|jsx)/` would also include JSON files, which led to babel to try to compile them.

I changed it to the following to only include js and jsx files :

```
test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/
```

Now everything works fine

Comment: You'r regex is incorrect; you should be using `/(\.jsx|\.js)$/,`